# Cannot find data in single MongoDB query using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to find the collection data by an single MongoDB query using Node.js. I am providing the collection below.

f_user_login:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5981b48654d471000459208e"
    },
    "email": "subhrajyoti.pradhan@oditeksolutions.com",
    "password": "d0e49bcba946540cb3d5fc808870d16b",
    "dob": "02-08-2017",
    "created_date": "2017-08-02 11:16:21",
    "updated_date": "2017-08-02 11:16:21",
    "status": 1,
    "token": "b85ff4c47093217587f8c7f2fff7ff86b1bcbf6a7321705871435929ee38",
    "verification_id": ""
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "598aa189e5f78d00042f48ae"
    },
    "email": "subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com",
    "password": "d0e49bcba946540cb3d5fc808870d16b",
    "dob": "1986-04-10",
    "created_date": "2017-08-09 05:45:44",
    "updated_date": "2017-08-09 05:45:44",
    "status": 0,
    "token": "",
    "verification_id": "7ffbe3f9be82b2af84491d3e8dff4fa1a65f973d"
}
```

I am providing my code below.

```
exports.userSignin=function(req,res){
    var email=req.body.email;//subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com
    var password=req.body.password;//d0e49bcba946540cb3d5fc808870d16b
    var pass=mden(password);
    if (email !='' && password !='') {
        db.f_user_login.count({email:email,password:pass,status:1},function(err,docs){
            if(docs > 0){
                token=crypto.randomBytes(30).toString('hex');
                db.f_user_login.update({email:email},{$set:{token:token}},function(err,doc){
                    db.f_user_login.find({email:email},function(error,docu){
                        var edata=[{"email": docu[0].email,"dob": docu[0].dob,"created_date":docu[0].created_date ,"id": docu[0]._id,"updated_date":docu[0].updated_date,"token_id":token}];
                        var data={"statusCode": 200,"data":edata,"message": "The user logged successfully."};
                        res.send(data);
                    })
                })
            }else{
                console.log(email,password);
                db.f_user_login.find({$or:[{email:email},{password:pass},{status:1}]},function(err,getdocs){
                    if (!err) {
                        var uemail=getdocs[0].email;
                        var upass=getdocs[0].password;
                        var ustatus=getdocs[0].status;
                        console.log('email,pass,status',uemail,upass,ustatus);
                        if (uemail != email) {
                            var data={"statusCode": 401,"error": "Unauthorized","message": "Invalid email id .Please provide a valid email id"};
                        }
                        if (upass != pass) {
                            var data={"statusCode": 401,"error": "Unauthorized","message": "Invalid Password .Please provide a valid Password"};
                        }
                        if (ustatus == 0) {
                            var data={"statusCode": 401,"error": "Unauthorized","message": "you have not verified your account using the link sent to your email."};
                        }
                        res.send(data);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here my input `email and password` is right and I need to check the status and get this `you have not verified your account using the link sent to your email.` message. But unfortunately both document has same password its always checking the first document but originally I need to check the second document for validation.

It is possible using 3 three different query but here I want to operate a single query. Is this possible?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do `getdocs[1]`? The `.find()` method passes an array of all matches, so if you need the _second_ match, I think you'd want the first index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for the entire process:

Note: Some typos or code may need to be changed. But you can use the basic idea.

```
 if (email !='' && password !='') {
   console.log(email,password);
   db.f_user_login.find({$and:[{email:email},{password:pass}]},function(err,getdocs){
    if (!err && /*check if the getdocs is not empty*/) {
        var uemail=getdocs[0].email;
        var upass=getdocs[0].password;
        var ustatus=getdocs[0].status;
        // update your collection from here with ID
        // Remember update is work fine with id
        console.log('email,pass,status',uemail,upass,ustatus);
        if (ustatus === 0) {
            var data={"statusCode": 401,"error": "Unauthorized","message": "you have not verified your account using the link sent to your email."};
        }else if(ustatus === 1){
            var data={"statusCode": 200,"data":edata,"message": "The user logged successfully."};
        }
        res.send(data);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: No,If email/password will be wrong. Here I need three different messages.

Comment: if email and password are wrong your getdocs will be empty. that's why is put /*check if the getdocs is not empty*/. if not resolved, i will drill more into it.